# Working on a Support Wiki, have some embedding questions

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, wiki, html

I'm trying to embed javascript that would allow me to create HTML links that open in new windows of a specific size.  Is this possible and, if so, how?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using? SharePoint 2007, 2010, 2013?

Answer (score 0):

Create the JavaScript in a separate notepad file and have the extension as .txt or .js (If you have the .txt extension to your file, make sure you have necessary script tags in the code)

save it and upload it to a library (Site assets or Style library) on your Wiki site.

Copy shortcut of your file and keep it handy.

Once the above steps are done, go to your page where you want to embed Javascript.

Edit the page > in the ribbon 'Editing Tools' > Insert > Web Part > 'Media and content' category > 'content editor' webpart.

Once you have the content editor webpart on the page, edit the webpart > Under the 'Content Link' 'To link to a text file, type a URL' paste the file shortcut that you have ready.